# how to join monthly reports into one table, SQL

Tags: sql

I'm new to data analytics, working on my first case study.  I have 12 tables that I created in my sql project, but i can't seem to figure out how to join them to have one yearly report.

I ran an `INNER JOIN` `ON` query for each table and no results returned.

I know this is probably an easy task and I'm making it too hard, I'm just new and confused.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TABLEname AS april20
INNER JOIN TABLEname2 AS may20 ON april20.ride_id = may20.ride_id
INNER JOIN TABLEname3 AS june20 ON april20.ride_id = june20.ride_id
INNER JOIN TABLEname4 AS july20 ON april20.ride_id = july20.ride_id
INNER JOIN TABLEname5 AS oct20 ON april20.ride_id = oct20.ride_id
INNER JOIN TABLEname6 AS nov20 ON april20.ride_id = nov20.ride_id
INNER JOIN TABLEname7 AS dec20 ON april20.ride_id = dec20.ride_id
INNER JOIN TABLEname8 AS jan21 ON april20.ride_id = jan21.ride_id
INNER JOIN TABLEname9 AS feb21 ON april20.ride_id = feb21.ride_id
INNER JOIN TABLEname10 AS mar21 ON april20.ride_id = mar21.ride_id
INNER JOIN TABLEname11 AS april21 ON april20.ride_id = april21.ride_id
```

for privacy sake, i censored the table names. but this is my most recent attempt. i got the green light to run the query, but not results were returned. i just need one "yearly report" from the 12  tables

Comment: You don't include enough information.  Do the field values actually match, that is are there rows in *all* of the tables that have the exact same ride_id field values so *all* of the matches in your `ON`s will succeed?

Comment: It sounds as if you really want to be using `UNION` rather than `JOIN` -- do your 12 tables have identical column structure or very close at least?

Comment: ^ good point.  I guessed they wanted to add more columns to each row ( `ride_id, jan feb mar apr may jun july...` = 1 row ), but if they want to instead add more rows with the same columns then they want UNION.

Comment: all of the tables have the matching structure except for one. julys table has one less column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your 12 tables are all identically structured then I believe that what you really are looking for is to use the `UNION ALL` clause rather than `JOIN`.

Try the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEname 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLEname2 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLEname3 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLEname4 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLEname5 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLEname6 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLEname7 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLEname8 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLEname9 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLEname10 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLEname11
```

Comment: thank you so much! I went back to the spreadsheet and made the columns consistent for each table, and tried UNION ALL and it worked!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I am please to have been of help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a separate table for each month's data.

1. That makes life harder than it needs to be. Put all your data in one table and SELECT the date ranges you need.
2. It looks like you need `UNION ALL` in place of `JOIN` because you want to concatenate several of these one-month tables together to get a one-year table.